# Is there an easy way to scan for surrounding bluetooth devices and get their RSSI to detect proximity in Python?

Tags: python, bluetooth, kivy, rssi

We have to create a prototype of a social distancing app, but are all relatively inexperienced programmers. Does any of you have an idea to do this?

I already setup Python and Kivy for the app development.

I was already looking into [Bluetooth Proximity Detection](https://github.com/ewenchou/bluetooth-proximity), but experiencing some troubles.
When running that:

```py
import bluetooth
print(bluetooth.discover_devices(duration=8, lookup_names=True, flush_cache=True, lookup_class=False))
```

I receive this error:
`ImportError: Cannot load LightAquaBlue framework, not found at /Users/thomask/PycharmProjects/Baap/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightblue/LightAquaBlue.framework`

But when trying to install Lightblue package, I get this error:
`The following build commands failed:   CompileC /Users/thomask/Downloads/lightblue-0.4-master/src/mac/LightAquaBlue/build/LightAquaBlue.build/Release/LightAquaBlue.build/Objects-normal/arm64/BBServiceAdvertiser.o /Users/thomask/Downloads/lightblue-0.4-master/src/mac/LightAquaBlue/BBServiceAdvertiser.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'LightAquaBlue' from project 'LightAquaBlue') (1 failure)`

Comment: Check out [Bluetooth Proximity Detection](https://github.com/ewenchou/bluetooth-proximity)

Comment: Thanks I was already looking into that, but experiencing some troubles.    
  When running: 
`import bluetooth

print(bluetooth.discover_devices(duration=8, lookup_names=True, flush_cache=True, lookup_class=False))`
       
I receive this error: `ImportError: Cannot load LightAquaBlue framework, not found at /Users/thomask/PycharmProjects/Baap/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightblue/LightAquaBlue.framework`

Comment: But when trying to install Lightblue package, I get this error: `The following build commands failed:
 CompileC /Users/thomask/Downloads/lightblue-0.4-master/src/mac/LightAquaBlue/build/LightAquaBlue.build/Release/LightAquaBlue.build/Objects-normal/arm64/BBServiceAdvertiser.o /Users/thomask/Downloads/lightblue-0.4-master/src/mac/LightAquaBlue/BBServiceAdvertiser.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'LightAquaBlue' from project 'LightAquaBlue')
(1 failure)
`

Comment: your last two comments should be added to your question.  This way the question better conforms to Stackoverflow guidelines in showing what you have already attempted.  Also, makes it easier for other potential responders.

Comment: since you haven't received any answers yet, I would suggest you post a new question just focused on the import problem you are having.  The github page mentions you need packages 1) bluetooth, and 2) python-bluez.  Are you having trouble installing `python-bluez`?  If so, in your new question you should provide 1) the install command you used, the complete error code, 3) Python version, 4) environment (i.e,. Unix, Windows, etc.), 4) IDE (i.e. Pycharm or Jupyter, etc.).